# Error al recorrer array dentro de otro array

Tags: array, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

Ya habia echo una pregunta similar solo que creo no la formule bien, y no supe donde editar la pregunta para formularla bien.
Estoy haciendo un pequeña aplicacion tipo carrito de compra con react y firebase, pero tengo un problema al querer imprimir los pedidos que se solicitaron.
mi hook para enviar el pedido es el siguiente:

```
import { db } from './firebaseConfig';
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

 const enviarPedidoCliente = async ({uidUsuario, fechaPedido, productosCarrito}) => {
   const pedido = productosCarrito.map((x) => {
    return(
  {
    codigo: x.codigo,
    nombre: x.nombre,
    cantidad: x.cantidad
  }
)
```

})

```
await setDoc(doc(db, "pedidosweb", '123456'), {
    uidUsuario: uidUsuario,
    fechaPedido: fechaPedido,
    pedido: pedido //este array contiene los productos seleccionados
  });
}

 export default enviarPedidoCliente;
```

quedando algo asi:
Array [ {…} ]
0: Object { fechaPedido: 1648705970, uidUsuario: "jxQIowAPWLMWqrsfgtt458IF4pOSL2", pedido: (3) […] }

lo que necesito es mostrar algo como esto:

Folio: 12345 | Fecha: 31/03/2022

- codigo: 12345678, nombre: producto 1, precio: 387, cantidad: 2
- codigo: 34567890, nombre: producto 2, precio: 231, cantidad: 10

Folio: 12346 | Fecha: 31/03/2022

- codigo: 45673378, nombre: producto 3, precio: 37, cantidad: 21
- codigo: 32678942, nombre: producto 4, precio: 31, cantidad: 1
- codigo: 34567890, nombre: producto 2, precio: 231, cantidad: 3

estoy ocupando .map() y el folio, fecha de cada pedido si se puede recorrer:

```
console.log(pedidos.map((x) => x.fechaPedido));
```

cuando hago un console.log a x.pedido puedo ver el array pero me sale de esta forma

```
Array [ (3) […] ]//esta estructura no se si esta correcta [[{...},{...},{...}]]
0: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

y si quiero seleccionar un atributo como

```
console.log(pedidos.map((x) =>  x.pedido.codigo));
```

me sale este error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: x.pedido is undefined
```

y si lo quiero mapear

```
console.log(pedidos.map((x) =>  x.pedido..map((d) => d.codigo)));
```

igual me sale este error, no se si la estructura de ese array es lo que me esta provocando el error o no se si estoy haciendo mal al querer mapear dentro de un map y return.
espero me puedan ayudar y antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Amigo/a, sería buena idea que muestres en la pregunta el array que te imprime x.pedido, que dices que se muestra en la consola así: [[{...},{...},{...}]] , de esa manera determinar mejor cual es el error. Igualmente, a simple vista, lo que parece que es tu array de pedidos esta dentro de otro array, es decir, puede el array de todos los pedidos, no esta en x.pedido, si no en x.pedido[0], que es lo que indica 0: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ], ahí lo que dice es que x.pedido es un array con un solo valor en el índice cero (0), y en ese índice cero es que tiene un array con tres posiciones tiene la información que deseas. Intenta hacer el map con x.pedido[0], si no es la solución, muestra lo que te muestra la consola.
Actualizacion:
edita tu comentario y pon el código que te da la consola no como respuesta a mi comemtario si no como un fragmento, que es una herramienta al publicar que te permite escribir codigo de esta manera

```js
const pedidos=[
  { 
    nombre: "ADEROGYL SOL 3ML/ CON 5 AMP", 
    codigo: "0007501165003040" 
  },
  {
    nombre: "JUST FOR MEN BARBA Y BIGOTE B-30 CASTANO MEDIO CON 60 ML", 
    codigo: "0007501080111462" 
  },
  {
    nombre: "JUST FOR MEN BARBA Y BIGOTE B-35 CASTANO OSCURO MEDIO CON 60 ML", 
    codigo: "0007501080111431" 
  }
];

pedidos.map(pedido => {
  console.log(pedido)
});
```

Comment: esto es lo que me imprime:Array [ (3) […] ]
​
0: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { nombre: "ADEROGYL  SOL 3ML/ CON 5 AMP", codigo: "0007501165003040" }
​​
1: Object { nombre: "JUST FOR MEN BARBA Y BIGOTE B-30 CASTANO MEDIO CON 60 ML", codigo: "0007501080111462" }
​​
2: Object { nombre: "JUST FOR MEN BARBA Y BIGOTE B-35 CASTANO OSCURO MEDIO CON 60 ML", codigo: "0007501080111431" }

Comment: e igual intente hacer el map con x.pedido[0] y de igual forma me aparece este error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: x.pedido is undefined